# Wrong return value of OBJECT_ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

> On Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU1) (KB3178925) - 12.0.5511.0 (X64) 
>       Aug 19 2016 14:32:30 
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

with the sp_UpdateStats actually doesn't existing, the query :

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('sp_UpdateStats')
```

returns the value : -838816646

and

```
select * FROM sys.objects WHERE name='sp_UpdateStats'
```

return 0 line...

How can it be ? A bug in OBJECT_ID function ?

**EDIT**

it's good to know that the ID -838816646 is comming from sys.sysobjects or sys.system_objects but then the question more precisely is :

- why does the procedure appear in sys.sysobjects and sys.system_objects and not in the sys.objects that is supposed to be the new view that we should use ?

Comment: From the [fine manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190324): "There is a version of this view with the same schema, called `sys.system_objects`, that shows system objects. There is another view called `sys.all_objects` that shows both system and user objects. All three catalog views have the same structure." `sp_updatestats` is a system object.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression  that `sp_updatestats` doesn't exist on your machine. It does. You couldn't have dropped it because system objects can't be dropped, barring the use of terrible black magics.

Comment: "why does the procedure appear in sys.sysobjects and sys.system_objects and not in the sys.objects that is supposed to be the new view that we should use ?" Because Microsoft designed it that way? You should almost never have any use for querying system objects in the first place, so they didn't put it in `sys.objects` but instead split the view into `sys.objects` for user objects only and `sys.system_objects` for system objects, with `sys.all_objects` if for some reason you really want *all* objects. It's true that Books Online neglects to mention this directly under "mapping system tables".

Comment: Yes but the title of the question is "Wrong return value of OBJECT_ID?" so it's interesting to "understand" from where is coming that ID  -838816646, but the real problem is that apparently, as the procedure doesn't exist in the database, the return value of OBJECT_ID is wrong... And so the function is not reliable ? And it's a bug so ?

Comment: But the procedure *does exist in the database*. Why on earth do you think it doesn't? Try `exec sp_updatestats` if you don't believe what `OBJECT_ID` is telling you.

Comment: Ok I understand :) this is a built in system procedure... I gave that name to a **personal** procedure... So after drop it exist only in sys.sysobjects or sys.system_objects and not in sys.objects

Comment: `sp_` is a prefix reserved for system stored procedures. Never use it for your own procedures, as it causes [a performance hit](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) and may break things going forward for applications that expect to see the system procedure rather than yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that useful final precision.

Answer (score 2):

It will be stored in `Master` database `sysobjects` view

```
select * FROM master.sys.sysobjects WHERE name='sp_UpdateStats'
```

Results : `-838816646`

Comment: Indeed it's in there sys.sysobjects... But I don't understand isn't it suppose to be depreciated that one and replaced by sys.objects ? And why does it appear in  sys.sysobjects as the procedure have been dropped ? is it a bug with that backward compatibility 'old' table ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.all_objects` to include system objects.

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.all_objects
WHERE  NAME = 'sp_UpdateStats'
```

The definition for this is actually in the resource database.